# how to use material-ui Dialog PaperProps

Tags: material-ui

I'm using v1.1.0 of material-ui in React 16.3.2. I'm trying to create a landing page similar to [Showcase - Local Insights](https://material-ui.com/discover-more/showcase/)

where the dialog has opacity (Find foreclosures). I'm trying to use PaperProps for Dialog component described here [Dialog doc](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/)

Here's a component I've created to try to do this.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

import ForwardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Forward';

import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';


const styles = theme => ({
  dialogPaper: {
    opacity: 0.5,
    border: '#FF0000 1px solid',
  },
  button: {
    margin: '30px'
  }
});

function Transition(props) {
  return <Slide direction="up" {...props} />;
}

class SignInDialog extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    username: ''
  };

  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="fab" color="primary" aria-label="add" className={classes.button} onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>
          <ForwardIcon />
        </Button>
        <Dialog
          PaperProps={styles.dialogPaper}
          open={this.state.open}
          TransitionComponent={Transition}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">WELCOME</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <p>SIGN IN</p>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
              <Input
                value={this.state.searchString}
                onChange={this.handleChange('search')}
                id="siginin-input"
                placeholder="Enter your username"
              />
            </FormControl>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Continue
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SignInDialog.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SignInDialog);
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to get the Dialog to take the styles. What is needed to get PaperProps to work?

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use `PaperProps` you have to specify the props of the `Paper`for which you are applying style.

```js
<Dialog
          PaperProps={{ classes: {root: classes.dialogPaper } }}
          />
```

You can also use `classes` property and override the style

```js
<Dialog
          classes={{paper:classes.dialogPaper}}
          />
```

Comment: thanks @siva_seeker.  yes, this works to style the dialog paper and I can use this. It'd still be interesting to know how to use PaperProps as it seems it's intended to do similar function -- unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to overide paper props is by using classNames

```
<Dialog
PaperProps={{ className: classNames(classes.dialogPaper) }}/>
```

Comment: You don't really need to use `classNames` unless you have multiple classes, or conditional classes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Dialog
          PaperProps={{ classes: {root: classes.dialogPaper } }}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

use custom class like :

```
  <Drawer
    PaperProps={{className: classes.classNameGoesHere}}
        ...
```